# mapbox when gps disable

Tags: android, location, mapbox

I make an Android app with mapbox based on the proposed example of the official documentation.

When GPS is desable or when GPS signal is weak, showing a user's location doesn't work.

however the app using well the HIGT_ACCURACY priority and data mobile is enable.

Any idea ?

thanks

edit*

```
private void enableLocationComponent() {
    if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this)) {
        LocationComponentOptions options = LocationComponentOptions.builder(this)
                .trackingGesturesManagement(true)
                .accuracyAlpha(0)
                .maxZoom(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.zoom_max))
                .minZoom(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.zoom_min))
                .accuracyColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.primary))
                .build();
        mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().activateLocationComponent(this, options);
        mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().setLocationComponentEnabled(true);
        mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().setCameraMode(CameraMode.TRACKING_COMPASS);
        mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().setRenderMode(RenderMode.COMPASS);
        mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().getLocationEngine().setPriority(LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().getLocationEngine().addLocationEngineListener(this);
    } else {
        permissionsManager = new PermissionsManager(this);
        permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this);
    }
}
```

location work perfectly fine if GPS is enable. 
location doesn't appear at all if GPS is diseable.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't work"? Is it that a user's location doesn't appear at all on app startup? Or that it doesn't display in the right location? If you could share some of your code and screenshots of the behavior, that would be helpful in surfacing a solution. 

There's also a step by step guide that walks through a basic location setup for the Mapbox Android Maps SDK: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-location-listening/

Comment: Thanks, i edit my post for more information. Also i see this [link](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/issues/478). " The only way around this would be to utilize Google-Play-Services within your project and use our `GoogleLocationEngine`"

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your post correctly, the issue is that there's no location shown when GPS is disabled on app startup?

The ticket you've [linked in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54813876/mapbox-when-gps-disable#comment96595082_54813876) is a bit dated so I wouldn't reference any of the code that's posted there, but the solution is certainly still valid.

### Context on why this happens

Instead of shipping a custom `LocationEngine` the SDK retrieves the best one it could find on the device. More detail on this [here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/core/overview/#locationengine).

You haven't shared this in your code snippet, but the best way to retrieve the most recent location update is to override the `onSuccess` method of the `LocationEngineCallback`. Like so:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LocationEngineResult result) {
    MainActivity activity = activityWeakReference.get();

    if (activity != null) {
        Location location = result.getLastLocation();

        if (location == null) {
            return;
        }


        // Pass the new location to the Maps SDK's LocationComponent
       if (activity.mapboxMap != null && result.getLastLocation() != null) {
            activity.mapboxMap.getLocationComponent().forceLocationUpdate(result.getLastLocation());
       }

     }
}
```

(Note that I snagged the above code from the [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/core/overview/#requesting-location-updates).)

If the device you're running your app on has no recent location information - which can happen if you've disabled GPS for an extended period of time - there will be nothing retrieved by the LocationEngine and the LocationComponent will have nothing to display.

### Why does adding the Google Play Services's LocationEngine solve the issue?

Several custom LocationEngines, Google's being one of the most common, use additional signals to confirm a device's current location (e.g. WiFi). As a result, even if GPS is disabled, the probability of the engine returning a `null` value is dramatically lower.

---

⚠️ Disclaimer: I currently work for Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: Okay thank you so much. However the HIGHT_ACCURACY priority, is not it supposed to use mobile data or wifi?

Comment: @pycoignard you found out whether it is so?